# A value of type List<dynamic> can't be returned from this function 'contacts' because it has a return type of List<Contact>?

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

I am using the dependency flutter_contacts for this code and this is for a provider file. Here is the code below :

```
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'main.dart';
import 'star.dart';
import 'package:flutter_contacts/flutter_contacts.dart';

class PRProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  final List<Contact>? _fivestar = [];

  List<Contact>? get contacts =>
      _fivestar.map((id) => contacts.getById(id)).toList();
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to archive ?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Hi Yesin thanks for answering. I want to be able to get the contact from the contactlist to the new list of fivestar. I want to achieve a small library of bookmarked contacts where people can access to their favorite contacts.

Comment: sorry but I think  your `_fivestar` should be `contacts` and then you can use a getter to the filter item like `get fivestar `